# Facebook Search Friend I may know ALSO lives in certain area

Tags: facebook, search, friends, location

I want to use Facebook to invite potentially interested people to an event. That event being an Arm Wrestling Tournament.

To efficiently locate people interested in Arm Wrestling criteria, I wish to search my friends very own friends list, in particular the section “Friends you may know.” Now this is not enough. I wish to take this task methodically. I want to do the previously described process while at the same time search people within a certain state. How can I do this?

I was thinking there may be a graph search using the Boolean  AND operator like:

friends I may know AND Live in West Virginia
 friends I may know that live in West Virginia

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to search by "friends you may know""

The closest Graph query will be

"Friend Name friends who live in West Virginia"

https://www.facebook.com/search/112083625475436/residents/present/FRIEND_ID_HERE/friends/intersect